# No provider for XHRBackend with Angular 2 and Http service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, webpack, ng-modules

I'm building a project based on angular2 (angularcli generated), webpack, scss, and module oriented.

For http request I decided to create a Service that is used by an Authentication service.

All referenced in a CoreModule

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RequestOptions, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';

// Services
import {HttpService} from './services/http.service';
import {AuthService} from './services/auth/auth.service';

export function httpInterceptor(backend: XHRBackend,
                                defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
  return new HttpService(backend, defaultOptions);
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: httpInterceptor,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

And my AppModule :

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

import 'materialize-css';

// Components
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

// Modules
import {MaterializeModule} from 'angular2-materialize';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {CoreModule} from './core/core.module';
import {AuthModule} from './auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterializeModule,
    CoreModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
  }
}
```

Here is the full issue :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for XHRBackend!
Error: No provider for XHRBackend!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9562)
    at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9637)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9576)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9558)
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9562)
    at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9637)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9576)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9558)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:770)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:741)
    at zone.js:818
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3924)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
    at <anonymous>
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
next @ core.es5.js:4562
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3621
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.triggerError @ core.es5.js:3993
onHandleError @ core.es5.js:3954
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:157
_loop_1 @ zone.js:653
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:662
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:592
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the `HttpModule` in your module. The latter provides the HTTP providers including `XHRBackend`. Moreover if you want to implement interception for HTTP request, you need to use the `Http` type when registering your interceptor implementation (a sub class of `Http`).

Here is a sample:

```
imports: [
  (...)
  HttpModule, // <-------------
  (...)
],
providers: [
  {
    provide: Http, // <-------------
    useFactory: httpInterceptor,
    deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Store, Injector ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I was indeed missing 'HttpModule' import inside CoreModule thank you :) I'm new to web dev, it's not that easy

Comment: @An-droid No worries, you're welcome! Keep in mind that Angular is modular ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the context (If I'm correct), try with an arrow function:

```
return () => new HttpService(backend, defaultOptions);
```

Anyways, why don't you add to your `AppModule`, in the `imports`, the module of Http (`HttpModule`)?

**AppModule:**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

imports: [ HttpModule ]
```

And **in your service** you just:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
         }

// Use Http's stuff
}
```

Then in your `CoreModule` you can just add:

```
providers: [ MyService ]
```